# search for column names from an array in R

Tags: r

The columns in my data frame are called col_rent, col_oil etc

I have a list of words in the array below. If you precede any of these with "col_", you get a column name.

```
> listofwords
 [1] "rent"
 [2] "pay"
 [3] "oil"
 [4] "gas"
 [5] "food"
```

I would like to find the index of each of these columns.

I tried to grep it as follows, I basically want to find column numbers of col_rent, col_pay, col_oil, col_gas, col_food without using a for loop

```
> grep(paste0("CM_",listofwords),names(dfread))
[1] 359
Warning message:
In grep(paste0("CM_", listofwords), names(dfread)) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

However, as the message says, it does not allow me to grep each member of the list. How can I do that so that I end up with a list of numbers, each showing the column name where these columns occur in the data frame.

Comment: Maybe `grep(paste0("CM_(", paste(listofwords, collapse = "|"), ")"), names(dfread))` ? Though I'm not sure why you using `"CM"` here while you are saying the columns names preced by "col_".

Comment: `match(paste0("col_",listofwords),colnames(dat))` ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks david, that was a typo on my part. My original data frame had columns called by CM_

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks. I was able to use it.

Comment: If this was a typo, I guess `grep(paste0("col_(", paste(listofwords, collapse = "|"), ")"), names(dfread))` should also work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should vectorize your operation:

```
sapply(paste0("CM_",listofwords), function( element ) {
grep(element,names(dfread))
})
```

It works for me like this:

```
> listofwords <-c( "rent",
+ "pay",
+ "oil",
+ "gas",
+ "food")
> as.array(listofwords)
[1] "rent" "pay"  "oil"  "gas"  "food"
> dfread <- data.frame( CM_pay = 0,
+                       CM_rent = 1,
+                       CM_aaa1 = 3,
+                       CM_oil = 2,
+                       CM_aaa2 = 7,
+                       CM_gas = 8,
+                       CM_food = 9
+                       )
> colnames(dfread)
[1] "CM_pay"  "CM_rent" "CM_aaa1" "CM_oil"  "CM_aaa2" "CM_gas"  "CM_food"
> sapply(paste0("CM_",listofwords), function( element ) {
+    grep(element,names(dfread))
+ })
CM_rent  CM_pay  CM_oil  CM_gas CM_food 
      2       1       4       6       7
```